# Change CSS Class height and width in javascript depending on screen res

Tags: jquery, screen-resolution

I want the size of a div class 'content' to change depending on the size of the users' screen resolution.

So far Ive written this javascript

```
function resize()
{

    if ((screen.width>1024)) { $(".content").style.width = 560 + "px"; $(".content").style.height = 315 + "px" }
    if ((screen.width>1280)) { $(".content").style.width = 640 + "px"; $(".content").style.height = 360 + "px" }
    else { $(".content").style.width = 853 + "px"; $(".content").style.height = 480 + "px" }
};
```

and obviously in the html I have the class '.content'

why is this code not working?

Comment: You may be better off looking at the browser size, not screen resolution. Shouldn't your content respond to the size of my browser, regardless of my screensize? I don't keep my browser fullscreen.

Comment: Why are you not using media queries?

Comment: My coding level is very poor at the moment. Ill look into media queries now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your specific issue here is that you are mixing jQuery and raw javascript.

To set the width of an element with jQuery, use the [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width) or [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

```
$(".content").width(560);
$(".content").css('width',560);
```

Having said that, you may be better off looking at the browser size, not screen resolution. Shouldn't your content respond to the size of my browser, regardless of my screensize? I don't keep my browser fullscreen.

Lastly, look at [css media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) even to respond to the browser size. There are much better ways of doing this.

Comment: You want to know how to set the height and the width? Use both of the jquery methods that I've show you. $(".content").width(560); $(".content").height(315);

Answer (score 2):

You can try and just use jQuery and CSS

```
   function checkWindowSize() {  

    if ( $(window).width() > 1800 ) {  
        $('content').addClass('large');  
    }  
    else {  
        $('content').removeClass('large');  
    }  

}  

$(window).resize(checkWindowSize);
```

For the CSS you would need to write it out like this:

```
#content{  

}  

.large #content{  

}
```

Here is a tutorial [Source](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-tutorials/quick-tip-different-layouts-for-different-widths/)